# how to run periodic task in high frequency in flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, apscheduler

I want my flask APP to pull updates from a local txt file every 200ms, is it possible to do that?

P.S. I've considered BackgroundScheduler() from apschedulerler, but the granularity of is 1s.

Comment: What kind of updates are you looking for? I assume you'd want to read the content? Or just detect if the file has changed? Please elaborate.

Comment: read the content, and then update the app global variable to the new content if there is a change

Comment: Best to check hash of the text file to detect changes as oppose to read the content just to find out.

Comment: It would be nice if it could be kept in hash. Unfortunately the text file is updated from time to time by some upstream source.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you put inside the function will be dealt for every 200ms.

```
import datetime, threading

def foo():
    print datetime.datetime.now()
    threading.Timer(0.2, foo).start()

foo()
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just start a loop in a thread that sleeps for 200 ms before the next iteration?